# Implement Sharing Location Places Picker same like WhatsApp without Places Picker Since it got deprecated

Tags: android, kotlin, google-places-api, google-places, google-places-autocomplete

We had a requirement of sharing location which is a similar kind of WhatsApp with respective to User Interface & functionality.

I have come across that Google Place Picker has got deprecated and also migrated to Places Clients.

Say Like as,

[image]

and when they are trying to search,

[image]

May be, I am not good at explaining my idea but overall I am in the search of the above kind of implementation.

And also I came to know that Google Charges for the search or the places from the below Url,

https://github.com/rtchagas/pingplacepicker

What all I have tired is,

**Coding Part:**

```
Places.initialize(applicationContext, "Google API Key")
placesClient = Places.createClient(this)



val autocompleteFragment =
          getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.autocomplete_fragment) as AutocompleteSupportFragment

autocompleteFragment.setPlaceFields(Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME));

autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(object : PlaceSelectionListener {
            override fun onPlaceSelected(p0: Place) {
                TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
            }

            override fun onError(p0: Status) {
                TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
            }
        });

 val intent = Autocomplete.IntentBuilder(
            AutocompleteActivityMode.FULLSCREEN, fields
        )
            .build(this);
        startActivityForResult(intent, AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE);
```

After searching for two three places I am get an error saying Retry. Don't know the reason.

Error:

[image]

Help is really appreciated.

Comment: Post your error log.

Comment: Updated Question @Ninja

Comment: Can you post error log?

Comment: I am starting an Intent AutocompleteActivityMode.FULLSCREEN.

Comment: do you really need places bar search ?

Comment: Suggest me if anything else can replace that ?

Comment: please check my suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem since i'm working with **place picker** within my app , but since google decided to remove it , i have no choice than have a work around to find a solution !

i decided to use google map to recreate a place picker close experience .

First i created the map as full screen , and i putted an `ImageView` (Marker) as overlay of it as xml below :

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <fragment
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.streetdev.goodnecity.SelectLocationPicker" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_map"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="56dp"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_plus"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/map"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end" />
 </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

So whenever the user is navigating on the map , the marker will stay in the center of the map like **place picker**

Now all you have to do is start your map picker using `startActivityForResult`, you have to handle the `cameraPosition` with **gps** ( if its available ) and then as soon as you want to go back with the result ( for me i click on the Fab button ) , you can get the result this way :

```
            LatLng latng = mMap.getCameraPosition().target;
            Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
            returnIntent.putExtra("result",String.valueOf(latng.latitude)+";"+String.valueOf(latng.longitude));
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
            finish();
```

The last step is to handle the result in `onActivityResult`, you get your result , you do a `split` using `";"` to separate latitude from longitude

hope my example will help some one !